# Посоветуйте как решить задачу с многопоточностью

Tags: java, многопоточность, spring, servlet

Здравствуйте. Мне нужно написать такую веб-программу:

1. Программа при запросе к Servlet'у возвращает некоторые данные.
2. Эти данные программа, берет из своей коллекции, например, List
3. Раз в минуту коллекция (List) обновляется данными из базы.

---

На первый взгляд это очень простая задача, но когда я стал думать о ней, то я решил, что она должна соответствовать следующим требованиям:

1. Программа не может обновить коллекцию, если в этот момент она отдает данные в servlet'е.
2. Программа не может отдавать данные, если коллекция в данный момент обновляется.

---

Вот примерно так я это себе представляю:

Класс для хранения данных:

```
@Component
class DataManager {

    private List<Object> cache = new ArrayList<>();

    public void updateDataFromDB(List<Object> cache) {
        this.cache = cache;
    }

    public List<Object> getDataInServlet() {
        return cache;
    }
}
```

Класс для обновления данных:

```
@Component
@EnableScheduling
public class Updater {

    @Autowired
    private DataManager dataManager;

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 60 * 1000)         //  вызываем раз в минуту
    public void update() {
        List<Object> cache = loadDataFromDb(); //  достаем кэш из базы
        dataManager.updateDataFromDB(cache);   // передаем его в
    }
}
```

Сервлет:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class BaseController {

    @Autowired
    private DataManager dataManager;

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "getData" , method = RequestMethod.GET )
    public List<Object> getData()  {
        return dataManager.getDataInServlet();
    }

}
```

---

Получается, что сразу много потоков могут параллельно обращаться к методу getDataInServlet, но нельзя чтобы  метод updateDataFromDB() и getDataInServlet() были вызваны параллельно.

Первой моей мыслью было просто сделать оба метода **synchronized**, но это очень плохо скажется на производительности.

Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, как можно решить эту задачу.

Comment: Давайте переформулируем вопрос, сералет должен отдавать данные из БД?

Comment: Здравствуйте. Сервлет должен отдавать данные из коллекции.  Коллекция меняет свое содержимое(обновляется), раз в минуту из базы.

Comment: ReentrantReadWriteLock в связке с try/catch блоком используйте. Почитайте вообще про пакет concurrent.*

Comment: @fantastic а кто обновляет коллекцию? И как сервлет получает к ней доступ?

Comment: А просто volatile или AtomicReference на поле cache вас не спасет?

Comment: Я добавил побольше кода в пример. Чтобы было было лучше понятно, что я хотел бы сделать.
@Nofate  не знаю, я слабоват в многопоточности.

Comment: Может быть, я зря надумал лишнего. И ничего плохого не случится если методы "отдать данные"  и "обновить данные" вызовутся параллельно.

Comment: +1 к совету Nofate. Сам synchronized на время установки/получения поля точно в одиночку бы не затормозил приложение - это может быть действительно заметно при количестве вызовов, на порядки превышающем RPS среднего веб-приложения.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. Программа не может обновить коллекцию, если в этот момент она отдает данные в servlet'е.
> 2. Программа не может отдавать данные, если коллекция в данный момент обновляется.

Сама постановка задачи сомнительна. Смотрите сами:

- Вашими даными владеет единственный экземпляр класса `DataManager`.
- Данные представленны ссылкой на коллекцию, лежащей в поле `cache`.
- Когда кто-то (сервлет) хочет получить доступ к данным, он получает копию ссылки на коллекцию при помощи метода `getDataInServlet()`.
- Когда кто-то (Updater) хочет обновить данные в `DataManager`, он просто заменяет ссылку, лежащую в поле `cache` на **новую** ссылку на **новый** `ArrayList` (при условии, что метод `loadDataFromDb()` создает новую коллекцию).

  Все, кто вызвал перед этим `getDataInServlet()` в своих потоках спокойно продолжают работать со своей ссылкой на **старую** коллекцию (по крайней мере пока не попытаются изменить данные в ней).

Исходя из вышеперечисленных утверждений, вам достаточно обеспечить *видимость* изменений поля `cache` для потоков. Дело в том, что согласно модели памяти Java, не существует гарантий на то, что изменения обычного поля одним потоком станут видным другим потокам. Для обеспечения такой гарантии нужно добавить к полю модификатор `volatile`.

```
private volatile List<Object> cache = new ArrayList<>();
```

---

PS. Насчет медленности `synchronized`. Если для JVM очевидно, что в данный  момент потоки не конкурируют за блокировку, то будет использована так называемая *fast-path* (или *uncontended*) синхронизация, которая не создает значительных накладных расходов. В вашем случае синхронизировать  предполагается геттер и сеттер, которые в любом случае будут отрабатывать быстро по отношению к коду, который их вызывает. Без профилировки и анализа говорить о потере производительности на `synchronized` в приведенном коде — преждевременно.